# How can I get the C++ compiler to deduce T indirectly?

Tags: c++, templates

My template-fu is rather weak. I have this code:

```
template<typename T>
void Foo(void(*func)(T*)) { }

void Callback(int* data) { }

int Test()
{
    Foo(Callback);
}
```

...but I'd like something more readable than C's nasty function pointer syntax of `void(*func)(T*)`.

Someone on my team suggested this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Types
{
    typedef void Func(T*);
};

template<typename T>
void Foo2(typename Types<T>::Func* func) {}

void Test2()
{
    Foo2(Callback);        // could not deduce template argument for 'T'
    Foo2<int>(Callback);   // ok
}
```

(I'm still debating whether this is actually more readable, but that's a separate issue.)

How can I help the compiler figure out what T is without needing to explicitly specify it in the caller?

Comment: I don't think the suggested solution is more readable. Even the opposite. But just my opinion.

Comment: Anything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context. In C++11 use alias templates: `template<class A> using Func = void(A*); template<typename T> void Foo(Func<T>* func) { }`

Comment: In your code, the callback has a `T*` param. How does `Foo` know what to pass on to the callback? This doesn't look like real code

Comment: Do you mind adding the function body of `Foo`, showing how it invokes `Callback`?

Comment: A parameter of function type is adjusted to pointer-to-function type, so you can also have a signature of `void Foo(void func(T*))` if you find that more readable.

Comment: Thanks @0x499602D2 - I didn't realize I could use this syntax. I think this is a great option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extract `T` from the function type using a traits class.

```
template<class F>
struct CallbackTraits;

template<class T>
struct CallbackTraits<void(*)(T)>
{
    typedef T ArgumentType;
};
```

Your example can be modified like this:

```
template<typename F>
void Foo(F func)
{
    typedef typename CallbackTraits<F>::ArgumentType T;
}

void Callback(int* data) { }

int Test()
{
    Foo(Callback);
}
```

This technique is used in the boost type-traits library:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html

This blog post goes into a bit more detail about the implementation of the technique:
https://functionalcpp.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/function-traits/

Unfortunately this approach hides the information in the signature of `Foo` about the constraints on the argument passed in. In the above example the argument must be a function of type `void(T*)`.

This alternative syntax does the same as the original example while being slightly more readable:

```
template<typename T>
void Foo(void func(T*)) { }
```

Another alternative syntax that may be more readable can be achieved using c++11's alias templates as follows:

```
template<typename T>
using Identity = T;

template<typename T>
void Foo(Identity<void(T*)> func) { }
```

Unforunately the latest MSVC fails to compile this, reporting an internal compiler error.

Comment: This is pretty good, and the only thing I don't like about this is the loss of documentation on 'func' to Intellisense. A reader is forced to go to a couple levels of IDE indirection to figure out what the constraints of 'F' are. Aside from adding a comment (which many Intellisense implementations will pick up), do you have any suggestions on how to keep some of the type documentation?

Comment: @scobi You could use `static_assert` to give a readable compile error unless unless `F` is an object type that can be called with the desired number of arguments and/or return type. What are the constraints on `F` in your example? I would probably also choose a better  name for `F` depending on the constraints - e.g. `CallableObjectType`. You could also use `std::enable_if` to prevent `Foo` being called with an argument that does not meet the constraints, but then it would fail silently.

Comment: Compile time constraints are fine but what I'm after is docs. When someone is calling 'Foo', they need to know what to pass in to it. Usually that's done with Intellisense telling you the arg type. I wouldn't like someone to have to compile (or thread through the source) to find out what the function actually wants. A name like CallableObjectType is an improvement, but not good enough to tell someone through Intellisense what it's expecting. Also: the constraints on 'F' in my example are that it must be a function that returns void and takes a T*.

Comment: @scobi The constrained `func` can be declared more readably as `void func(T*)` or `Identity<void(T*)> func` as in the edited answer.

Comment: Yeah I think after all of this, I'm going to just go with the void func(T*) style, which is by far the most readable. Enlightening discussion though!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to deduce the type based on a nested name: there is no reason why different instantiations of the outer type won't define an identical inner type. You *could* use a `using` alias, though:

```
template <typename T>
using Function = auto (*)(T*) -> void;

template <typename T>
void Foo(Function<T>) {
}
```

Personally, I would recommend against using any of that, however: in practice it seems much more advisable to actually take a function object which later allows using object with suitable function call operators to be used. For callbacks it is quite common that you'll need to pass in some auxiliary data. That is, you would either use an unconstrained template or one which takes a type-erased type, depending on what you want to do exactly:

```
template <typename Fun>
void Unconstrained(Fun fun) {
}
template <typename T>
void TypeErased(std::function<void(T*)> fun) {
}
```

The unconstrained version has the advantage that it can potentially inline the function call but it has the disadvantage that every function object type creates a new instantiation and that the argument types are likely to vary. The type-erased version effectively has to do something like a virtual function call but there is just one instantiation of the function template (per argument type `T`, of course).

Admittedly, the type-erased version's type won't be deduced from a function pointer (or any other argument which isn't a `std::function<void(X*)>`), i.e., you may want to have a forwarding function

```
template <typename T>
void TypeErased(Function<T> fun) {
    TypeErased(std::function<void(T)>(fun));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++98 and C++03 template argument deduction only works with functions (and methods).

I don't think the picture changed in the more recent standards.